# Remove class from active child elment

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, carousel

I'm using bootstrap carousel, and i want to be able to remove class `d-none`
on image container that contain active class, 
So i have

```
$(".carousel-control").click(function() {
$(".work-c-box").addClass('d-none');
    var focusedEl = $(".carousel-inner").find(".active .work-c-image .work-c-box:nth-child(2)");

  focusedEl.removeClass('d-none');
```

if i inspect in Dev Tools it removes d-none class, but not to my focused [active] it removes it from element that was in that condition in previous click event.

i try using .prev() function, but no luck, or real good understanding of a problem :)

this is html part

```
 <div id="carousel-1" class="carousel slide multi-item-carousel" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">

  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <div class="item__third work-c-image">
        <img src="image.jpg" alt="" >
        <div class="work-c-box">
            <h3>some Heading</h3>
            <p>dummy text</p>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item__third work-c-image">
        <img src="image2.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="work-c-box box-hide">
            <h3>some heading</h3>
            <p>dummy text</p>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item__third work-c-image">
        <img src="image3.jpg" alt="" > 
        <div class="work-c-box box-hide">
            <h3>some heading</h3>
            <p>dummy text</p>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#carousel-1" class="left carousel-control" role="button" data-slide="prev"></a>
  <a href="#carousel-1" class="right carousel-control" role="button" data-slide="next"></a>
</div>
</div>
```

what i need is a little hint and explanation, not just answering my question with some code.

Thanks

Comment: as i remember, bs carousel has some events. For example when the slide is changing, before change and after change. Try using those events to remove the class. Also try to share the html structure or event better create a working example code snippet so we can help you better

Comment: You can override css rules of d-none class.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code

```
$($(".carousel-inner").find(".active .work-c-image .work-c-box:nth-child(2)").parent().parent()).removeClass('active');
```